# Compiling Tesseract Debugger to visualise region classification

Tags: java, tesseract

I'm trying to follow [the instructions](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ViewerDebugging) on how to compile ScrollView.jar. I'm on Mac 10.10.2.

So far I've downloaded and installed tesseract 3.04 and downloaded the relevant jars:

```
brew install tesseract --HEAD 
cd /Library/Caches/Homebrew/tesseract--git/java
wget -O piccolo2d-core-3.0.jar "http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/piccolo2d/piccolo2d-core/3.0/piccolo2d-core-3.0.jar"
wget -O piccolo2d-extras-3.0.jar "http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/piccolo2d/piccolo2d-extras/3.0/piccolo2d-extras-3.0.jar"
```

Unfortunately, I don't know java, nor am I a proper computer scientist(!), so I don't know how to build the jar from the ScrollView.java source. Can any advice be provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, this worked for me:

```
### Install version 3.0.4
brew install tesseract --HEAD


### Build the scollviewer jar for the debug tool
## To get jars for the debug viewer
cd /Library/Caches/Homebrew/tesseract--git/java
# cd /usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/HEAD
wget -O ./piccolo2d-core-3.0.jar "http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/piccolo2d/piccolo2d-core/3.0/piccolo2d-core-3.0.jar" 
wget -O ./piccolo2d-extras-3.0.jar "http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/piccolo2d/piccolo2d-extras/3.0/piccolo2d-extras-3.0.jar"
make ScrollView.jar
```

---

**EDIT**

Get the homebrew package manager at: http://brew.sh/. Then you can get wget (and tesseract as above) using:

```
brew install wget
```

You also need to ensure you have apple's Xcode to use make. You can get this in the app store.

Comment: Tip: you must install tesseract using the `--HEAD` option (`brew install tesseract --HEAD`) for this to work, otherwise the `/Library/Caches/Homebrew/tesseract--git/java` won't exist.

Comment: failed on macOS 10.12.1.  `no such file or directory: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/tesseract--git/java`